# COUNTIF with IMPORTRANGE result keep showing only 0 or 1? WHY?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, countif

I have one spreadheet that includes name, id and amount of numbers data in it and i want to make the report in other spreadsheet.

i want to count the name column that is not blank, so i type this

=COUNTIF(importrange("gsheet link","Payroll 16-31 Jan!B3:B"),"<>")

but the result is "1" in fact that there are 3670 names on the column

=COUNTIF(importrange("gsheet link","Payroll 16-31 Jan!B3:B"),"<>"&"")

but still not working
can someone help?

I want to get the exact calculation of those data

Answer (score 1):

Two things:  have you connected the spreadsheets? If not, use IMPORTRANGE outside COUNTIF, something like `=importrange("gsheet link","A1")` . Accept the permissions and see if COUNTIF now does it right

If it doesn't, try with COUNTA that is specifically defined for counting non blank cells:. `=COUNTA(importrange("gsheet link","Payroll 16-31 Jan!B3:B"))`